# Different WordPress front page for logged out and logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress

The WordPress reading settings can be found under Settings > Reading.

I have the WordPress 'Front page displays' option set to 'Static front page'.

My 'Front page' is set to 'About'.

I am trying to have a different front page for logged out and logged in users. Currently everyone views the 'About' page when they visit example.com.

- If I visit example.com when logged out I want to see my 'about page'
- If I visit example.com when logged in I want to see my 'contact page'

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can either make a redirect to a page if not logged in or just show different content on the base url, which would you prefer?

Comment: Hi Nick M. I'd prefer to show different content on the base URL.

Comment: I have tried using if ( is_front_page() && is_user_logged_in() ) and then trying to display a template that isn't the front page template but this didn't quite work

Comment: Update your answer to show us your code. This should work.

Comment: Nick M - the code I used did identify when the front page was being viewed by a logged in user but it didn't set the WordPress 'front page' - which is what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to set the `front page` programmatically but not sure if this is a solution to your question, so, paste this code in your `functions.php` file and give it a try

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'Contact Me');
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
else {
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'About Me' );
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```

**P/S:** Not tested, just try it and please response what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. When I use it in my theme's functions.php this doesn't actually change the front page from what I have set in WP Admin. Note: I added a semi-colon to the end of the 2nd line

Comment: Can you just make sure that your page has same `title` I've used here in `get_page_by_title()` function ? Because, I've a page with title `Portfolio` and if I use `get_page_by_title('get_page_by_title')` and related code, it just changes the front page.

Comment: Yes, i can confirm i am using the exact title. Does the is_front_page() check need to be in there? We want the front page to be changed if a user is logged in, regardless of whether we are viewing the front page.

Comment: It is 5am here so I will try again in the morning. Thanks

Comment: Thank you RCV this works nicely. To make the solution a little more user proof, could the get_page_by_title be done by slug instead? Page slugs are less likely to change than the page title.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that has this problem you could just add this to the `header.php`, at the very top before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $newURL = 'http://YourWebsiteURLhere.com';
        header('Location: '.$newURL);
    }
} ?>
```

**OR** you can add this to Functions:

```
function homepage_template_redirect()
{
    if( is_front_page() && is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect(get_page_link('contact'));
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'homepage_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Is that a HTTP redirect you're using?

Comment: It's using PHP `header function`..`location:`. so it happens instantly.

Comment: sorry, I mean't that. It might be better to use a HTTP redirect hooking to `template_redirect`

Comment: hmm, would something like on my updated answer make more sense?

Comment: I feel more comfortable with the HTTP redirect. I think using the header function to redirect might happen slightly too late

Comment: THIS is the right way to start... I do not like the solutions suggesting to update_option and set the front page according to something, which might take some users in the wrong page.
+1 For this answer

Answer (score 2):

In the body of your page-about.php (or which ever template file the About page is using) you just need to use a conditional statement.

```
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>


content for logged in users


<?php } else { ?>


content for non logged in users


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, that is an approach I had thought about. However, I really need to know more about how WordPress sets a 'front page' - my question is - is there a way to set 2 different front pages depending on the user's logged in or logged out status?

Comment: Not sure you can accomplish this without editing core files, I've no idea. An approach you can use would be to have a landing page set as your home page, and then use get_template_part('logged_in_page') if logged in and get_template_part('not_logged_in_page') if not.

Answer (score 0):

- Edit: Didn't see your comment before I posted my answer.

You could add this to your functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'my_redirector');

function my_redirector(){
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/contact_us'); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

It's not a great solution to hard code in your url, but you could pick up the URL in other ways.

Comment: Thanks but I need to view the content on the base URL example.com. This redirect would take me to example.com/page-name

Comment: It would be better to redirect to home_url().'/contact_us'

Answer (score 0):

UserPro plugin gets this done easily. Just enter the URL you want logged in users to see instead of the normal homepage. So Simple!