# Set different page for logged in and guest user in wordpress with polylang support

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

```
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $page = pll_get_post(1713);
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
else {
    $page = pll_get_post(4142);
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```

This is a code , Which was modified from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039607/different-wordpress-front-page-for-logged-out-and-logged-in-users) . The idea is not to redirect but to set a homepage for different kinds of user . I'm using [Membership 2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/membership/) . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this run? What is the question? Is there a problem?

Comment: Sorry , I didn't mention it clearly. This code doesn't work. Its in my child's theme's function file.